# A space is $T_1$ iff every neighborhood of $p$ contains an infinite subset of $S$.

Tags: general-topology

$(X, \tau)$ is a $T_1$ space if and only if the following holds:

if for all $S \subseteq X$, then $p \in X$ is a limit point of S if and only if every open neighborhood of $p$ contains an infinite subset of $S$.

I've never seem a double if and only if like this, so far what I have managed to do is prove that if $(X, \tau)$ is a $T_1$ space and $S \subseteq X$ with $p \in X$ a limit point of $S$ then every open neighborhood of $p$ contains an infinite subset of $S$.  Also I've shown the converse of this if and only if, what I'm having trouble with is the converse of the first if and only if.

I need to show that if $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space such that if for all $S \subseteq X$ then $p \in X$ is a limit point of $S$ if and only if every open neighborhood of $p$ contains an infinite subset of $S$.

My thoughts so far:  I thought I would split it into cases where case $1$ is where $p$ is not a limit point of $S$ and case $2$ is where $p$ is a limit point of $S$.  I can't seem to make any progress from there, any help is appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note about this condition on subsets $S$ is that if $S$ is finite then it can't have limit points.  So to prove that $X$ is $T_1$ take $p, q \in X$ and let $S = \{p\}$.  As $S$ is finite, $q$ is not a limit point, so there is a neighborhood of $q$ that doesn't intersect $S$.

Comment: Wow, so obvious.  Thanks a lot!